# Парсер ютуба сработал, но ничего не записалось в файл: data.txt

Tags: python-2.x

Парсер ютуба сработал, но ничего не записалось в файл: data.txt

Это сам скрипт:

```
   # coding: utf8
# == pars_playlist.py
# == select short information from Yotube playlist -- 
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

print   "pars_playlist working..."

# == get first linkof playlist ==
url = raw_input('input link:')
url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLku9se_HAVOrs3p_jJzZAbV3BEODrhS3j"

fh = open('data.txt', 'w')

cur_num = 1     # index of reading page
try: 
        while True:
            # -- get curent page --
            print cur_num
            print url
            content = urlopen( url )
            page = content.read()   

            # -- cut head
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
            body = soup.find('body')

            # get current title
            span = body.find(id="ecw-title")
            title = span.getText()
            print title

            # get list of all links
            ol = body.find(id="playlist-autoscroll-list")
            lis = ol.findAll('li')

            # soup for current page
            for idx, li in enumerate(lis): # seek for picture
                li_title = li["data-video-title"] 
                if li_title  == title: break
            video_id = li["data-video-id"]

            # get picture information
            img = li.find('img')
            img_src = img['src']
            pos = img_src.find('?')
            if pos > 0: img_src = img_src[:pos]

            # get description of page
            descr = body.find(id="eow-description")
            descr_text = descr.getText()

            # save information
            fh.write(title.encode('utf8') + '\n')
            fh.write(video_id.encode('utf8') + '\n')
            fh.write(img_src.encode('utf8') + '\n')
            fh.write(descr_text.encode('utf8') + '\n')
            fh.write('\n')

            if idx >=len(lis) -1: break

            # get next url
            idx += 1
            li = lis[ idx ]
            anc = li.find('a')
            href = anc['href']
            url = "https://www.youtube.com" + href

            cur_num = cur_num + 1

    # == 05 end of work ==
except: 
    print "exception: " + str(cur_num)
    pass
finally:
    fh.close()
    print "ok"
```

Comment: У вас не находится элемент с идентификатором ecw-title и `body.find(id="ecw-title")` возвращает `None` у которого вы пытаетесь вызвать метод getText что приводит к исключению.

Answer (score 1):

В питоне (в отличие от PHP и, возможно, каких-то ещё языков) точка НЕ используется для соединения строк. Используйте для этого плюс:

```
print "exception: " + str(cur_num)
```